# Changing date format with dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, f#

First, I am aware I can format the date any way I want, the question is not about that.

I'm wondering how dotnet chooses its format:

Since I'm in the EU I've dumped the American format and adopted a the more logical  yyyy/mm/dd or dd/mm/yyyy, etc.

I'm on MacOS and the date and time settings are in dd/mm/yyyy.

But when I do print a date through .ToString(), the date is still in the US format.

Specifically, the debugger will display all DateTime objects in the US format.

I am not sure where DotNet is getting its locale information but this has become problematic at the beginning of the year (I was looking for a 2nd January record that was in fact 1st February) just because I picked the date from the debugger.

Does anyone know what DotNet is using to set its own locale?

Comment: why the f# tag?

Comment: C# get the default format from `Control Panel -> Region` setting on Windows.

Comment: By default .net uses the date format configured in your OS. `DateTime.ToString()` offers an overload to override that format: `DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))`.

Comment: Alternatively you can override the default format by setting the culture of the current thread, so you don't have to do it each time you call `DateTime.ToString()`: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")`.

Comment: That's the issue I have here: the OS is configured to use an EU date format and dotnet doesn't seem to follow that. I know I can configure it in dotnet, but I'm trying to find out where it reads the default locale from the OS to find the issue.

Comment: I just tried this on macOS and I get *'English (United Kingdom)'* if I print `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NativeName` via `dotnet run`, but if I run/debug in Rider I see *'Invariant Language (Invariant Country)'*. Google suggests [others have noticed the same](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010261419-Is-Rider-overriding-how-the-culture-is-being-determined-) in (at least) Rider & VS Code.

Comment: @CharlesMager, I read the thread and yes, I think that's exactly the problem described there. Most likely it works when exporting the locale, I'll see if there is a bug filed in the Jetbrains' db

Comment: Additional note about custom format: If you really want to nail down slash as date separator and colon as time separator, then you have to escape these in the custom format string. Otherwise the separators will come from the user's configuration, which might be dash for date and dot for time. Example: @"yyyy//MM//dd HH/:mm/:ss". Without the alpha in front it will be the ugly "yyyy////MM////dd HH//:mm//:ss" because you're escaping once for the slashes in the string and again for the custom datetime format.